# Getting friends using the same application on Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, playframework

I'm using play framework to create a facebook application. I'm kinda stucked at some point. With Graph Api i can't take a list of friends who use my application. What i want to say is for example:

A is using my application.

B is using my application too and B is a friend of A.

When A is using my application, I want A to see B is also using this application.

Simply I want to get list of friends using same application.

How would i do that with Graph Api?

Answer (score 11):

There is a field called "is_app_user" on the user table that you could run a FQL query against.  The query would be something like:

```
select uid, name 
from user 
where is_app_user = 1 
and uid in (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
```

The graph url for that would be like this (remember to add an access token):

[https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=select uid, name from user where is_app_user = 1 and uid in (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())&access_token=...](https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=select%20uid,%20name%20from%20user%20where%20is_app_user%20=%201%20and%20uid%20in%20%28SELECT%20uid2%20FROM%20friend%20WHERE%20uid1%20=%20me%28%29%29&access_token=...)

Answer (score 0):

With Friend A's access token do a Post to `me/friends` to get the list of friends. See if Friend B is on the list. See: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/